# How do you access the DOM node in jquery inside of a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html

```
<div id="list_item_template"><li><a href="#">Text</a></li></div>
```

and javascript:

```
var item = $("#list_item_template").clone();
```

What I want to do is access the inner `<a>` tag of the cloned copy and add an attribute.  Without cloning I would just do:

```
$("#list_item_template a").attr("onclick", "SomeFunction()");
```

However, I need to perform that operation on the cloned copy, not on the html currently on the page.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`item.find('a');` should do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#list_item_template a").attr("onclick", "SomeFunction()");
```

is not advisable... [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825533/jquery-setting-onclick-attribute-working-only-on-firefox/2825564#2825564)...

use `.click()` instead...

```
$("a",item).click(SomeFunction);
```